# Activate (show) 'title' HTML attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, safari

I have a website where the translations for static text are shown "on-hover" (while the user is hovering over the HTML element (e.g. h1, label, span)). This behaviour is implemented using the '[title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)' HTML attribute.

Some of the users are using iPads to browse the website, so I need to know if it possible to combine iPad's touch gestures to activate (show) the 'title' attribute. To be more specific, I want to know if it possible to show title using JavaScript (as it was hovered with a mouse).

Comment: If you only can explain, how you physically "hover" on a touch screen ...

Comment: I don't. I thought about touch-and-hold gesture for one second which will trigger JS code which in turn will activate (show)  the HTML element's title.

Comment: "touch-and-hold gesture for one second" is pretty much the same as right click on a mouse.

Comment: Even so, do you have any suggestion on how to implement the "show title on hover" feature in touch screen devices?

Comment: A "hover" on touch screens simply doesn't exist. You've to contact device manufacturers and ask them to implement "hover" feature (Maybe something like "put the finger over the element on the air, close but not touching the screen" ..?)

Comment: Maybe I'll do it later ;)
For now, do you have any suggestion for an alternative for how to integrate touch gesture with 'title' HTML attribute?

Comment: Again: There's no such feature for touch screens, it's impossible. You could implement something like tap on the screen, and then drag over the element, but that's not standard behavior, it 's not worth of all the work because your users don't know about it. Usually hover effects on touch screens are replaced with a small clickable icon.

Answer (score 0):

The hover event in touch devices do not work in the way as it works in the PCs and laptops.

In touch devices,
the hover event is triggered when the user clicks on the element and it closes when the user clicks some where else.

So the title text is shown when the user clicks on it and it disappears after the user clicks some where else on the screen.

If you want the the title element to be displayed when the user places his/her fingers on the element **(touching it)** you have to handle html touch events and also create your own tooltip.

there is some explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-tag-title-attribute/)

Answer (score 0):

I had same use case, among others, which is why I created a small standalone utility class to handle this functionality elegantly both for desktop and mobile.

[InfoPopup](https://github.com/foo123/InfoPopup)

Hope it is helpful.